# Use if clause in sub query to set value for update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table of data

```
id | name |  Car  |  Bike  |
------------------------------------
1  | me   |   1   |    0   |
2  | you  |   0   |    1   |
```

And I want to update it in my `tax` table from:

```
tax_id | name | net  |  Car | Bike | Home | Total |
---------------------------------------------------
   1   |  me  | 100  | NULL | NULL |  10  |   10  |
   2   |  you | 1000 | NULL | NULL |  100 |   100 |
```

to:

```
tax_id | name | net  | Car | Bike | Home | Total |
---------------------------------------------------
   1   |  me  | 100  |  5  |   0  |  10  |   15  |
   2   |  you | 1000 |  0  |   20 |  100 |   120 |
```

with rules

- car = net*0.5
- bike = net*0.2
- home = net*0.10
- total = car + bike + home

I tried to use:

```
UPDATE tax
SET
    tax.Car = (
               IF (SELECT Car FROM DATA WHERE ID = 1) > 1
                   BEGIN
                       RETURN tax.net * 0.5
                   END 
               ),
     tax.Bike = (
               IF (SELECT Bike FROM DATA WHERE ID = 1) > 1
                   BEGIN
                       RETURN tax.net * 0.2
                   END 
               ),
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: i also try to set it on variable first but it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows is a possible solution. Points to note:

1. Please setup any future SQL questions in this way (i.e. creating the sample data ready to use) as makes it much easier to answer and you will get more/faster assistance.
2. The `IF` statement (in SQL Server) is for control flow only, not for conditional values in statements. Instead use [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
3. I have assumed you meant 0.05 and 0.02 respectively (as opposed to 0.5 & 0.2) as this was the only way to get the results you require.
4. Note the sub-query, used to allow us to make use of intermediate results to calculate the `Total` column. Which is then joined onto the original table to allow us to apply the updates.

```
    declare @Test table (id int, [Name] varchar(32), Car bit, Bike bit);
    declare @Tax table (tax_id int, [Name] varchar(32), Net money, Car money, Bike money, Home money, Total money);

    insert into @Test (id, [Name], Car, Bike)
    values (1, 'me', 1, 0), (2, 'you', 0, 1);

    insert into @Tax (tax_id, [Name], Net, Car, Bike, Home, Total)
    values (1, 'me', 100, null,null, 10, 10), (2, 'you', 1000, null, null, 100, 100);

    --select * from @Test;
    --select * from @Tax;

    update T set
      Car = Y.Car
      , Bike = Y.Bike
      , Home = Y.Home
      , Total = Y.Total
    from @Tax T
    inner join (
    select tax_id, Car, Bike, Home,  Car + Bike + Home Total
      from (
        select tax_id
          , case when exists (select 1 from @Test T where T.id = tax_id and T.Car = 1) then Net else 0 end * 0.05 Car
          , case when exists (select 1 from @Test T where T.id = tax_id and T.Bike = 1) then Net else 0 end * 0.02 Bike
          , Net * 0.1 Home
        from @Tax
      ) X
    ) Y on Y.tax_id = T.tax_id;

    select * from @Tax;
```

Returns:

```
tax_id  Name    Net Car Bike    Home    Total
1   me  100.00  5.00    0.00    10.00   15.00
2   you 1000.00 0.00    20.00   100.00  120.00
```